# Arrays: filter based on inner arrays values

Tags: php

What is the smartest way to filter this multidimensional array to get only the arrays with `['virtual'] == true`??

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=13)
      'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
      'label' => string 'Nombre' (length=6)
      'sortable' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'property_to_show' => boolean false
      'image' => boolean false
      'virtual' => boolean false  <<<<<<<<<
      'filter_parameter' => boolean false
      'link' => boolean false
      'entity' => boolean false
      'boolean' => boolean false
      'route_parameters' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'text' => string '' (length=0)
      'route' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=14)
      'virtual' => string 'true' (length=4)  <<<<<<<<<<<
      'label' => string 'Usuarios' (length=8)
      'link' => boolean true
      'class' => string 'DefaultBundle:User' (length=18)
      'entity' => string 'User' (length=4)
      'filter_parameter' => string 'company' (length=7)
      'text' => string 'ver' (length=3)
      'sortable' => boolean false
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'property_to_show' => boolean false
      'image' => boolean false
      'boolean' => boolean false
      'route_parameters' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'route' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=14)
      'virtual' => string 'true' (length=4)  <<<<<<<<
      'label' => string 'Productos exclusivos' (length=20)
      'link' => boolean true
      'class' => string 'DefaultBundle:Product' (length=21)
      'entity' => string 'Product' (length=7)
      'filter_parameter' => string 'company' (length=7)
      'text' => string 'ver' (length=3)
      'sortable' => boolean false
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'property_to_show' => boolean false
      'image' => boolean false
      'boolean' => boolean false
      'route_parameters' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'route' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: how should `'virtual' => string 'false'` be treated? also, `'virtual' => string '0.00'` ... ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use array filter for this:

```
array_filter($array, function($value) {
   return !empty($value['virtual']);
});
```

Comment: `!empty($value['virtual'])` already checks that `$value['virtual']` is true

Comment: Ah, you correct, will edit :)